# subset a large data set based on two factors and name it systemically

Tags: r, subset

Suppose I have a data frame(name: "Students") of students of 10th class of Arizona State which has columns of **ID number, Hair color, Eye Color and Weight**. There are 5 types of Hair Color and 4 types of Eye Color. Hair colors are discretized(1-5) and so are Eye colors(1-4)

I want to make 20 new subsets/data-frames of names "x_Students_y"  where x_Students_y denotes a data-frame/subset of Students having Hair Color x(anything out of 1-5) and Eye color y (anything out of 1-4). How can we do it?

(Note, Discretization(for example) : Hair Color: 1: black, 2: blue, 3: Brown, 4: Red, 5: Grey)

Comment: Please consider providing few lines of your dataset and expected result based on that

Comment: You'll be best served by following the advice of @akrun, but until then, look at the `dplyr` package and `filter()`.

Comment: Students data frame: <br/> ID Hair Eye Weight <br/>   2134  2  1 71  <br/> 2135 1 4 70 <br/> 2136 3 1 67  <br/>   we have to create new data frames which are subsets based on hair color and Eye color.  e.g. 1_Students_1, 1_Students_2, 1_Students_3, 1_Students_4, 2_Students_1, ....   5_Students_4

Answer (score 1):

Using base R:

```
df <- data.frame(hair=sample(4,20,replace=T),
                eyes=sample(letters[1:4],20,replace=T),
                foo=rnorm(20),
                bar=runif(20))
 frames <- split(df,paste0(df$eyes,'_students_',df$hair))

 # and in case you want the data.frames defined in the local environment
 list2env(frames,as.environment(-1))
```